# How can I recover a Microsoft Office 2013 product key?

Tags: microsoft-office-2013, product-key

I have Office 2013 installed on one of my computers but I have misplaced the product key. It is not set up through my Microsoft account and I would prefer it not be.

How can I recover the license key so I can move the installation?

I've tried running

> cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs" /dstatus

but that only gives me the last 5 characters of the product key. Obviously I need the whole thing.

I've also tried using various 3rd party products (ProduKey, Magic Jellybean Keyfinder, etc), but so far all seem to fail finding Office '13 keys.

Any advice?

Comment: http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

Comment: Will Belarc find it? I'll give it a try

Comment: According to my google resources, it will work for Microsoft Office 2013. :)

Comment: Huh. Just found that and was about to comment. See what happens.

Answer (score 0):

**[LicenseCrawler](http://www.klinzmann.name/licensecrawler.htm)**

Is perfect if you need to reinstall a program or operating system .

This does include the Windows product key but also other serial numbers for applications like Nero, Office, VMWare and pretty much every other application.

Comment: Talk about some ad offensive software.  I cannot suggest this. It did some strange things in my Sandbox testing, configured Office 2010 for some reason, and nagged me to register even though its free for personal use.  Belarc displays the same products this does and displays zero ads.

Comment: @Ramhound ya it does ask for resisting but we use this in our IT department and it does great job- its clean software